# Call rest web service from SQL Server 2008 using stored procedure

Tags: web-services, sql-server-2008, rest, stored-procedures

I have an xml created from a SQL query through a stored procedure. I need to call a REST web service with that xml and get a response. I am using SQL Server 2008. Is there a way to do it from the stored procedure?

I keep seeing links to use SQL CLR to access the web service. In those links, I need to create a SQL Server project / .NET framework. I do not see those templates / options in my Visual Studio 2008 or SQL Server Management Studio.

Is there a way to call this https rest web service directly from the stored procedure?

===============

I am using the SQL CLR to do this. But somehow the xml is not getting passed right. I get a 500 error. Could you please see if there is anything wrong with this code.

```
public static void SampleWSPost(SqlString weburl, out SqlString returnval)
    {
        string url = Convert.ToString(weburl);
        string feedData = string.Empty;
        ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = null;
            HttpWebResponse response = null;
            Stream stream = null;
            StreamReader streamReader = null;


            XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("D:\\CXmls\\crmXml.xml");
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(reader);
            reader.Close();

            request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
            mycache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential("username", "password"));   
            request.Credentials = mycache;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "text/xml";

            string data = xmlDoc.InnerXml;
            byte[] bytedata = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            newStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length);
            newStream.Close();

            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            streamReader = new StreamReader(stream);
            feedData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
            streamReader.Dispose();

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SqlContext.Pipe.Send(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
        returnval = feedData;
    }
```

Comment: No, not directly - SQL Server is a **database server** - it isn't designed or optimized to handle web service calls - that would be the job of an **application server**. You *can* use a SQL-CLR procedure to do this - or just rearchitect your solution not to require the database to call a web service ...

Comment: @marc_s I updated the question with my sql clr procedure. I am calling the xml from a shared drive and passing into the web service call. I am not sure if this is the right way of reading the xml  because I am getting a 500 error. Something wrong with the way I am reading this?